# WebView cannot find objects exposed via addJavascriptinterface in Lollipop

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I've been struggling with this for too long now. I hope anyone can help me. Here is my situation:

In our Android app, we route XMLHttpRequests from our WebView via Java/Android so we can add an OAuth2 token and track the requests. This worked fine until Android 5 got released.

Starting Android 5, the following exception is being raised whenever the WebView tries to interact with the exposed object in JavaScript:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com/company/android/AndroidXMLHttpRequest$AjaxRequest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/webview/webview.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/webview/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Invalid name: com/company/android/AndroidXMLHttpRequest$AjaxRequest
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 6 more
```

Results on different configurations:

- This code works fine on **physical and virtual devices** running Android < 5.
- This code breaks on **physical devices** running Android 5 and 5.1
- This code works fine on a **virtual device** running Android 5.0
- This code breaks on **virtual devices** running Android 5.1
- There is no difference between running a debug or production build

Some info about the code:
 * WebViewFragment gets initiated in `MainActivity.onCreate`.
 * `WebViewFragment.onCreateView` creates object to be exposed to WebView
 * JavaScript interface gets added in `WebViewClient.onPageFinished`
 * The class that is exposed is Public
 * All methods of the class that are exposed are public and have the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation

Starting Lollipop, WebView has been decoupled from Android so it can be upgraded via the Play Store. This is also something that shows from the error:

```
DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/webview/webview.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/webview/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

I looked at the release notes to discover if we have to do something different regarding WebView and addJavaScriptInterface but I can't seem to find anything.

Anyone has any ideas what could be the reason that it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for that, there was a bug in WebView: http://crbug.com/491800

The bug has been introduced in Android 5.1, so the original 5.0 works fine (the emulator). But on physical Lollipop devices with Play Store, WebView gets updated to a later version (43), which was still broken. The fix came out with WebView version 44, which I think is rolling out just now.

However, there is a workaround. In the injected method that accepts an instance of `AjaxRequest`, you need to replace the argument type to `Object`, and then convert to `AjaxRequest` later in the function (see [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491800#c15) for an example). This way, WebView will stop trying to look up the class which it can't access at that point.